# limpiar código de un proyecto para subirlo al SVN

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, vscode, svn

Tengo la necesidad de subir un proyecto a un repositorio `SVN`

En si son dos proyectos ..

```
 1. Proyecto Android realizado en Android Studio 
 2. Proyecto Flutter realizado en Visual Studio Code
```

Mi duda es la siguiente

Que debo de hacer para subir solo lo necesario y no todo el contenido de mi actual carpeta donde está el proyecto.

Según he visto en otros ejemplos que suben solo lo principal (algunas cosas esenciales), después al bajarlo y al compilarlo se descarga lo demás.

¿Cómo puedo hacer lo mismo?

Comment: En el archivo .gititnore puedes excluir lo que no quieres que sea versionado por el repositorio. Puedes indicar un archivo en específico o puedes indicar una carpeta completa

Comment: entiendo.. pero como se que archivos o no debo de subir.. por mi subo todo pero no es lo correcto.

Comment: Aumm bueno eso depende, como regla general solo debes versionar el codigo fuente y archivos de configuración, además de los archivos inherentes a la construcción del mismo, por ejemplo imagenes, iconos, etc... Como ejemplo de cosas que no se deben versionar serían los archivos que se generan al compilar la aplicación, archivos de configuración específicos de la máquina donde programas (ejemplo: tu archivo de configuración de proyecto del android studio),de nuevo nada que se autogenere al compilar o en tiempo de ejecución, cosas así. Saludos!

Comment: gracias .. entiendo muy bien lo que me comentas, habrá algún plugin o algo referente que me ayude a subir solo los archivos necesarios ?, justo he descargado un proyecto (flutter y vsc) Y NO PESA NADA. pero al ejecutarlo y compilarlo se genera todo lo necesario .. igual muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira ésta web que encontré https://www.gitignore.io/ colocas una tecnología y te hace el gitignore la acabo de agregar a mis favoritos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo de varias formas, la primera es agregar dentro del archivo **.gitignore** (crearlo si no existe) que se debe encontrar en la raíz del proyecto, los directorios o archivos que no deseas sean versionados.

Como ejemplo el caso de un proyecto de Android Studio, se agregan:

Los directorios:

```
.gradle/
.idea/
/build
/gradle
```

Si tienes varios módulos debes agregar todos los directorios:

```
app/build/
```

Los archivos:

```
/local.properties
/gradle.properties
**/*.iml
gradlew
gradlew.bat
```

---

También lo puedes realizar desde `Android Studio`, puedes seleccionar los archivos:

`File` > `Settings` > `Version Control` > `Ignored Files`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo recomendable es principalmente los directorios `/build` ya que estos generan una gran cantidad de archivos al construir tu proyecto y no es necesario versionarlos.