# ¿Qué va en .gitignore?

Tags: android-studio, git, github

En mi camino de aprendizaje tengo una duda, que archivos debo ignorar si estoy en el entorno de Android Studio? Por ejemplo en Node se ignora Node_modules pero en android no estoy seguro. Busque en algunos repositorios e internet y esto fue lo que encontré.

Espero puedan ayudarme, saludos!

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files bin/ gen/ out/

# Gradle files .gradle/ build/ .externalNativeBuild/


# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc) local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files .navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder captures/

# Intellij
*.iml .idea/ .idea/workspace.xml

# Keystore files
*.jks

# Fastlane fastlane/report.xml

# Bitrise configuration bitrise.yml

# NDK files
**/.cxx
```

Comment: Básicamente ahí se agregan todas las rutas que en proyecto que no deben ser utilizadas por [GIT](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-The-Command-Line). Estos pueden ser desde archivos de configuración hasta credenciales o variables de entorno las cuales no es recomendable compartir en público.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la regla general es: `ignora cualquier archivo que sea producto del proceso de compilación`... y otros archivos que solo apliquen a tu ambiente (por ejemplo, la metadata del IDE).

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore

Answer (score 1):

El archivo `​.gitignore` indica a Git los archivos o directorios que deseas no sean versionados, el archivo debe ser colocado en el directorio raíz de un proyecto.

En Android estos son los archivos que se ignoran generalmente:

```
#DIRECTORIOS
.idea/
.gradle/
/build
/gradle
/captures   
#ARCHIVOS
**/*.iml
gradlew
gradlew.bat
*.apk
```

Revisa las respuestas:

[No funciona correctamente .gitignore al versionar un proyecto Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112525/no-funciona-correctamente-gitignore-al-versionar-un-proyecto-android)

[limpiar código de un proyecto para subirlo al SVN](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/244979/limpiar-c%C3%B3digo-de-un-proyecto-para-subirlo-al-svn)

---

Te sugiero revisar la [**documentaciòn Git - .gitignore**](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

• Una línea en blanco no coincide con ningún archivo, por lo que puede servir como separador para facilitar la lectura.

• Una línea que comienza con `#` sirve como comentario. Coloque una barra invertida ("`\`") delante del primer hash para los patrones que comienzan con un hash.

• Los espacios finales se ignoran a menos que estén entrecomillados con barra invertida ("`\`").

• Un prefijo opcional "!" que niega el patrón; cualquier archivo coincidente excluido por un patrón anterior se volverá a incluir. No es posible volver a incluir un archivo si se excluye un directorio principal de ese archivo. Git no enumera los directorios excluidos por razones de rendimiento, por lo que los patrones en los archivos contenidos no tienen ningún efecto, sin importar dónde estén definidos. Ponga una barra invertida ("`\`") delante del primer "!" para patrones que comienzan con un "`!`" literal, por ejemplo, "`\!important!.txt`".

• La barra inclinada / se utiliza como separador de directorios. Los separadores pueden aparecer al principio, en la mitad o al final del patrón de búsqueda .gitignore.

• Si hay un separador al principio o en el medio (o ambos) del patrón, entonces el patrón es relativo al nivel de directorio del archivo .gitignore en particular. De lo contrario, el patrón también puede coincidir en cualquier nivel por debajo del nivel `.gitignore`.

• Si hay un separador al final del patrón, el patrón solo coincidirá con los directorios; de lo contrario, el patrón puede coincidir con archivos y directorios.

Por ejemplo, un patrón `doc/frotz/` coincide con el directorio `doc/frotz`, pero no con el directorio `a/doc/frotz`; sin embargo `frotz/` coincide con `frotz` y `a/frotz` que es un directorio (todas las rutas son relativas al archivo `.gitignore`).

Un asterisco "`*`" coincide con cualquier cosa excepto con una barra. El personaje "`?`" coincide con cualquier carácter excepto "`/`". La notación de rango, p. Ej. `[a-zA-Z]`, se puede usar para hacer coincidir uno de los caracteres en un rango. Consulte fnmatch (3) y el flag  `FNM_PATHNAME` para obtener una descripción más detallada.

Dos asteriscos consecutivos ("`**`") en patrones que coincidan con el nombre de ruta completo pueden tener un significado especial:

• Un "`**`" inicial seguido de una barra inclinada significa que coinciden en todos los directorios. Por ejemplo, "`**/foo`" coincide con el archivo o directorio "`foo`" en cualquier lugar, lo mismo que el patrón "`foo`". "`**/foo/bar`" coincide con el archivo o directorio "`bar`" en cualquier lugar que esté directamente debajo del directorio "`foo`".

• Un "`/**`" final coincide con todo lo que hay dentro. Por ejemplo, "`abc/**`" coincide con todos los archivos dentro del directorio "`abc`", en relación con la ubicación del archivo `.gitignore`, con profundidad infinita.

• Una barra seguida de dos asteriscos consecutivos y luego una barra que coincide con cero o más directorios. Por ejemplo, "`a/**/b`" coincide con "`a/b`", "`a/x/b`", "`a/x/y/b`", etc.

• Otros asteriscos consecutivos se consideran asteriscos regulares y coincidirán de acuerdo con las reglas anteriores.